Simulator Failing to find realtime match with Game Center
I'm able to authenicate in to Game Center with the Xcode Simulator just fine but when I try to find a realtime match it immediately fails and says no players found. Doesn't even try to time out, just instantly fails.
With actual devices it matches correctly and I'm able to start up a realtime match no problem.
Is there a new simulator setting that could be causing this? I've tried everything I can think of so far - checking firewall, fresh simulators.
Anyone else running into this? Using devices for testing is a bit of time consuming.
Using latest Xcode 15.4 and iOS 17.5.
